# How to put different size vectors in data.table column

Tags: r, data.table

I have implemented a simple group-by-operation with the `?stats::aggregate` function. It collects elements per group in a vector. I would like to make it faster using the data.table package. However I'm not able to reproduce the wanted behaviour with data.table.

Sample dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c"), val = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","D","A","B"))
```

Output to reproduce with data.table:

```
by_group_aggregate <- aggregate(x = df$val, by = list(df$group), FUN = c)
```

What I've tried:

```
data_t <- data.table(df)
# working, but not what I want
by_group_datatable <- data_t[,j = paste(val,collapse=","), by = group]
# no grouping done when using c or as.vector
by_group_datatable <- data_t[,j = c(val), by = group]
by_group_datatable <- data_t[,j = as.vector(val), by = group]
# grouping leads to error when using as.list
by_group_datatable <- data_t[,j = as.list(val), by = group]
```

Is it possible to have vectors of different size in a data.table column? If yes, how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
data_t[, list(list(val)), by = group]
#   group      V1
#1:     a   A,B,C
#2:     b A,B,C,D
#3:     c     A,B
```

The first `list()` is used because you want to aggregate the result. The second `list` is used because you want to aggregate the val column into separate lists per group.

To check the structure:

```
str(data_t[, list(list(val)), by = group])
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ group: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
# $ V1   :List of 3
#  ..$ : Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 2 3
#  ..$ : Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 2 3 4
#  ..$ : Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 2
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

---

Using dplyr, you could do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(val = list(val))
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#
#   group         val
#  (fctr)       (chr)
#1      a <S3:factor>
#2      b <S3:factor>
#3      c <S3:factor>
```

Check the structure:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(val = list(val)) %>% str
#Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ group: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
# $ val  :List of 3
#  ..$ : Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 2 3
#  ..$ : Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 2 3 4
#  ..$ : Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 2
```

Comment: To make it (maybe) easier to read, one can switch the outer list for a dot: `.(list(val))` in the data.table case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option with `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
res <- df %>% 
        nest(-group)
str(res)
#'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ group: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
# $ data :List of 3
#  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  1 variable:
#  .. ..$ val: Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 2 3
#  ..$ :'data.frame':    4 obs. of  1 variable:
#  .. ..$ val: Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 2 3 4
#  ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  1 variable:
#  .. ..$ val: Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 1 2
```

Comment: I thought of that too but we should note that it creates a list of data.frame whereas the data.table version creates a list of factors. Btw, I think the printing can still be improved if you look at `iris %>% nest(-Species)` for example

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks for the comment.  I didn't get the `printing` part.

Comment: I'm just saying that running `iris %>% nest(-Species)` creates a not very readable output (tidyr 0.4.1)