# aggregate multiple rows in dataframe to list

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am trying to convert data from multiple rows in a data frame to a list (or similar structure).

My data looks like this:

```
data.frame("a"=c(1,1,2,3,3,3), "b"=c("x","y","x","x","y","z"))
  a b
1 1 x
2 1 y
3 2 x
4 3 x
5 3 y
6 3 z
```

and the result I'm looking for is something like this:

```
  a       b
1 1    x, y
2 2       x
3 3 x, y, z
```

I can do this inefficiently by looping over all rows of the dataframe and appending to individual lists, but I wanted to see if there was a better way of doing this (I am currently studying the data.table package and I believe it contains a solution for this, but I haven't found it yet)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600416/ for some examples

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933958

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(b~a, df, FUN=toString)
#  a       b
#1 1    x, y
#2 2       x
#3 3 x, y, z
```

Or with `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'a', `paste` the elements of 'b' together (`toString` is a wrapper for `paste(..., collapse=", ")`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(b= toString(b)), a]
```